# Center a button in a navigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I would like to center a button in my navigationBar, which is currently defined as a rightBarButtonItem :

```
UIBarButtonItem *audioBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(toggleAudioPlayback:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = audioBtn;
[audioBtn release];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `.titleView` property of your navigation item - but you'll need to create your own assets for this (you won't be able to use a UIBarButtonItem). From Apple's docs:

> ...(titleViews) can contain buttons. Use
>   the buttonWithType: method in UIButton
>   class to add buttons to your custom
>   view in the style of the navigation
>   bar. Custom title views are centered
>   on the navigation bar and may be
>   resized to fit.